# C++ system() not giving output of dsget command

Tags: c++, command, system

This is weird... Am on Windows 7 in a domain environment, doing a quick program to process a bunch of data [so no lecturing me on the evil of using system()  =P ], and I've got this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  system("dsget group \"CN=Accounting,OU=Groups,OU=Exchange Users,DC=MyDomain,DC=com\" -members");
}
```

The output is nothing at all.  Stuff I've tried:

1. Ran that command verbatim on a command prompt, successfully got data back.
2. Did a "cout" on that command string to make sure the \" part was being processed right.
3. Did system("ipconfig -all") and other system commands to make sure that was working.
4. Did system("echo [dsget_command] > runThis.cmd") then system("runThis.cmd")... the only output was seeing it try to execute the dsget statement but still no results.

It's so weird that this is just happening to me on the "dsget" command, and also so weird that the command runs fine on a command prompt [not through the C++ program].  Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you need to run dsget as an administrator ?

Comment: I just tried your code, changed CN, OU and DC to match my domain, and I got the output. What compiler you are using? What settings? Unicode, UTF8, ASCII?

Comment: remi I don't need to run it as an administrator.  @wishmesh I'm just using the MinGW g++ compiler on Windows 7 64-bit, like: g++ program.cpp -o program

Comment: Visual C++ 2010 shows the output